# What do I do if I want to execute ls command everytime I do a cd to any directory?

Tags: command-line, bash, bashrc

Most of the time when I do a `cd` command I also do a `ls` to see what other files or folder are in that directory. So I want to execute `ls` everytime I change the directory. I know I can do `cd foo && ls` but is it really necessary to do `&& ls` everytime?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There are 2 ways to do this. You can create an alias as LnxSlck posted or another one is creating a function in .bash_aliases

```
mycd(){ cd "$1" && ls; }
```

Comment: Hey, you answer is working!

Comment: Make sure to quote the parameter expansion, otherwise it will fail if the directory contains special characters, like whitespace. `mycd() { cd "$1" && ls; }`

Answer (score 1):

I use the following, which doesn't involve adding any new commands:

```
cd() {
  builtin cd "$@"
  local status=$?
  [ $status -eq 0 ] && ls
  return $status
}
```

This makes `cd` work the same as before, except that there's also an `ls`.

Note the following implications: The other examples don't permit arguments to `cd`. While admittedly those arguments are uncommon, this is a 100% compatible drop-in replacement. And because it returns `cd`'s exit status, it won't break scripts.

There's one caveat here. If you ever *don't* want this functionality, you have to call `builtin cd`. But my experience in using this function for many years is that such occurrances are rare, occurring primarily in scripts, and the convenience of not having to type something long like `mycd` every time you want to change directories greatly outweighs the minor drawback of typing `builtin cd` once in a blue moon.

Answer (score 0):

You can make an `alias` for `cd`, and add it to your *bash_profile* or *bashrc*, something like:

```
alias 'mycd'='cd $1 && ls'
```

put that in your `.bashrc` . It is however recommended that you store all your aliases in `~/bash_aliases` file, so create the file using `touch ~/.bash_aliases` if it's not already present and use it to store all your *aliases.*

Comment: It's recommended that you add aliases to `~/.bash_aliases` . That way it stays separate from rest of the config files :)

Comment: its doing the `ls` part (when I do `mycd Desktop`, it prints the desktop), but isn't changing the directory to desktop.

Comment: I guess that doesn't work because in alias you can't have another command after param or else it will be taken as input for the param. `alias foo='echo $1 && echo bar'`, `foo moo` outputs `bar moo` instead of expected `moo bar`

Comment: You need a shell function here. Aliases aren't up to the task.